# How to fetch data about current user in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, identity

So, I added a new Parameter to my **ApplicationUser** class, which is called **SocialName**. I would like to display it when user is logged in, at the top right corner. There, we have this piece of code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello, " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Now the thing is, I would like to display parameter other than Current user's username. I found passing the model to the **Partial View** problematic because I need to do it for every single action, otherwise I will have **Null Reference**. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily display info about user in partial view by Html.Action() method without passing info to every action. For example:

**Your page/layout/...:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @Html.Action("HeaderUserInfo", "Common")
</ul>
```

**CommonController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult HeaderUserInfo()
{
    var user = _workContext.CurrentUser; //get info about user
    var model = new HeaderUserInfoModel
    {
        Username = user.Username,
        UserId = user.Id
    };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**and partial view HeaderUserInfo.cshtml:**

```
@model Models.Common.HeaderUserInfoModel

<span><i class="icon fa fa-user"></i> @Model.Username</span>
```

Comment: The **CurrentUser** property is invalid, it does not exist. Should I initialize something else than database in the **CommonController** Constructor? Like User Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user from this code:

`ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());`

You can have this in your controller or view then user with all properties will be available for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is the link to solve your problem exactly. Its seems that you can get the output by using the simple extension method.

Kindly follow the below link , in that asker had a same problem and finally provided the good solution. Hope it will be helpful for you too.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1957500.aspx?How+to+access+custom+Identity+or+ApplicationUser+properties+